# Yii - search data in model from action in controller

Tags: php, model-view-controller, model, yii

I'm Yii newbie trying to write simple application.
I'm writing "events" module and what I'm trying to achieve is to get data by writing date in URL.

So for example I've got URL like this: index.php/event/date/2011-11-19
I created Event controller and  It's working OK. I can even go with index.php/event/1 to load event with PK(id) = 1.

But what I want is to be able to give event_date (field in model/database) and to get all events from this day.

I've tried something like this:

```
public function actionDate($event_date=null) {

            $events=Event::model()->findAll("event_date = " . $event_date);

    $this->render('view', array(
        'model' => $events,
    ));
}
```

But I've got error: Call to a member function label() on a non-object. Anyone know a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Event::model()->findByPk($id);` returns single instance of your `Event` class (one object with  this `$id`)

When you use `Event::model()->findAll("event_date = " . $event_date);` - you work with array of objects, that matches your criteria

So, try write

```
if (!empty($events)) {
    $this->render('view', array(
        'model' => $events[0],
    ));
}
```

Comment: I've also change criteria when using "findAll", but it's working now. Thank You :)